# How to dynamically cast something?

Tags: java

I want to dynamically cast something by calling something like this:

```
Object genericObject = new MyObject();
MyObject myObject = getObject(genericObject, MyObject.class);

public static final T getObject(Object object, Class<T> clazz){
    if(isInstance(object, clazz)){
        return object;
    }
    return null;
}
```

How to fix the `getObject()` method so that it works?

Comment: What's the point? What's wrong with `(MyObject)genericObject` or `Class.cast()`?

Comment: Checks can be performed depending on primitive/reference data types, and make it neater.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Class#cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-):

```
public static final <T> T getObject(Object object, Class<T> clazz) {
    if(clazz.isInstance(object)) {
        return clazz.cast(object);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Also note the change to the method syntax by adding `<T>` @Mureinik made. Wouldn't compile without it.

Comment: Or use `return (T) object;` --- Because of type-erasure, the method becomes `Object getObject(...)` anyway, and the call becomes `MyObject myObject = (MyObject) getObject(...);`, so the `(T) object` cast is eliminated and only the `(MyObject) getObject(...)` cast is retained. With `clazz.cast(...)` you actually end up casting twice. Not really an issue, since casting is fast, and JIT will likely eliminate it anyway, but ...